# SQL - Self Join to get parent properties along with some properties of all its children

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table called `plant_location`. A single plant location can have multiple samplePlantlocation thus the self-join(ON parent_id)

`tree_count` and `name` is the number of plants planted on that plant location (i.e loc_abc)

I want to fetch all the samplePlantLocations with its measurements, tag, guid, geometry and plantedSpecies with its names and tree_count

```
SELECT spl.guid, spl.measurements, spl.tag,
COALESCE(ss.name, ps.other_species, pl.other_species) AS name,
ps.tree_count, spl.geometry
FROM planted_species ps 
INNER JOIN plant_location pl ON ps.plant_location_id = pl.id 
LEFT JOIN scientific_species ss ON ps.scientific_species_id = ss.id
LEFT JOIN plant_location AS spl ON pl.id = spl.parent_id
WHERE pl.guid = 'loc_abc'
```

I tried grouping this but I was getting a lot of duplicates.

How can I write a query to group the data so that I get following

```
{result : {
   plantedSpecies: [{
        "scientificName": name,
        "treeCount": treeCount
    }],
   samplePlantLocations: [{
        "measurements": measurements,
        "tag": tag,
        "guid": guid,
        "geometry": geometry
   }]
}}
```

Comment: Your SQL query doesn't seem to have much in common with the output you want (JSON). Because `spl` can return multiple rows for each `pl.id` you should get that part as a -correlated- subquery returning a single JSON (array) string; this applies to your other joins like plant_location (if it can return multiple rows for each `pl.id`.